# Importing .sql file into new DB use SSMS

Tags: sql-server, file, import, ssms

I have been instructed, at school, to create a operational DB in SSMS. I was given a .sql file containing the following queries.

```
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '1-24', '8/1/2012', '125/80', 125.8, 45, 5, 'No progress'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '1-24', '8/15/2012', '125/80', 126.7, 45, 4, 'Better'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '1-24', '8/27/2012', '130/70', 125.9, 60, 3, 'Happy'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '1-24', '9/7/2012', '125/70', 124, 48, 6, 'Bad week'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '1-24', '9/18/2012', '124/70', 125.8, 50, 3, 'Much improved'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '2-3', '8/1/2012', '145/80', 148.4, 55, 8, 'Very sad'
EXECUTE usp_RecordPatientVisit '2-3', '8/15/2012', '144/70', 148, 54, 6, 'Better'
EXECUTE RecordPatientSymptoms '1-24', '8/1/2012', 'Restlessness'
EXECUTE RecordPatientSymptoms '1-24', '8/15/2012', 'Restlessness'
EXECUTE RecordPatientSymptoms '2-3', '8/1/2012', 'Nausea'
```

I was given no other files or sources. I have no other files or raw data.

When I execute these queries, in a fresh DB, I get the following result

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'usp_RecordPatientVisit'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 2
Could not find stored procedure 'usp_RecordPatientVisit'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 3
Could not find stored procedure 'usp_RecordPatientVisit'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 4
Could not find stored procedure 'usp_RecordPatientVisit'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 5
```

What do these errors mean?

To access this file, I went to FILE>OPEN>FILE... within SSMS.

My Instructor insists that he has given me all I need to create a operable  DB but I feel that I'm missing some type of data file or some type of configuration step. Again, I have no other files or raw data. Am I uploading this file properly or is my database lacking pertinent information to be function?

Comment: Have you confirmed you're pointed at the correct database? If in SSMS, you see "master" in the upper left hand corner, you're executing against the master database. The stored procedure `usp_RecordPatientVisit` likely doesn't exist there, which would give you that error. Can you provide the name of the database you should be using?

Comment: We aren't here to do your school work for you, but maybe this is the purpose of the assignment?  The error is telling you it can't run `usp_RecordPatientVisit` because there is no such thing.  Either you're in the wrong dB (seems to contradict the task of creating an operational db) -- or you maybe need to write said stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, as @Dan mentions, you need to be working in a database the stored procedure has been executed in to be able to call to it. If you are setting up a new database, you will likely need to get the stored procedure from your instructor.

Comment: Thanks to all.  Resolved. My instructor was no help in the matter. The answer was with labs that were never assigned prior. Thanks again.